# Swift equivalent of inputStream, Outputstream and bluetoothSocket

Tags: swift, bluetooth

I am looking for equivalent of inputStream, OutputStream and BluetoothSocket in Swift.

What do we use when we are coding with Swift instead of those things in Android?

I have an app for Android now I want to create for iOS as well.

Comment: Simply said, there are no direct counterparts. You cannot rewrite the functionality 1-1 only changing names of classes.

Comment: Hi Sulthan, Thanks for your reply. Could you please share with me some basic information? As far as I know for the bluetooth connection I must use CBCentralManager, CBPeripheral, CentralManagerDelegate and etc. Am I in right path or not?

Answer (score 2):

Typically Android's BluetoothSocket is used with SPP, which is not available on iOS. How you need to redesign this depends on what you're doing, what your firmware offers, and how much control you have over the Bluetooth device's development.

For MFi(*) devices, iAP2 (via [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory#)) is very similar to SPP, so the same basic protocol and designs can be used. But in most cases, you have to develop a completely different protocol (most commonly over BLE GATT). CoreBluetooth and the class you've listed (CBPeripheral, etc) are how you interact with BLE GATT.

You can also dig into [L2CAPP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbl2capchannel). It provides an interface similar to SPP, but I haven't worked with any firmware ADK that supports using it as an alternative.

(*) MFi is "[Made for iPhone](https://mfi.apple.com)," and requires an extra chip in the hardware and has to go through Apple certification. It's worth looking into if you're building your own hardware. It gives you a few extra capabilities, though not nearly as many as people expect.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) already commented:

> Simply said, there are no direct counterparts. You cannot rewrite the functionality 1-1 only changing names of classes.

- For BLE devices use [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) framework.
- For Bluetooth Classic you need to use [External Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) framework (only for MFI accessories).

Comment: ExternalAccessory doesn't really give you access to Bluetooth Classic in the way most people mean. It only gives you access to iAP2, which does run over a "classic" connection (it's very similar to SPP), but you get no access to other profiles, or to the BR/EDR channel. Ironically, CoreBluetooth now *does* give you access to a "classic" protocol via "GATT over BR/EDR," but this is rarely very useful (and also isn't what most people mean when they ask for "classic").